# lists, use index and keeping their names

Tags: list, names

I have two lists:
`>list1<-list(a1=c("a11","a12","a13"), a2=c("a21","a22","a23"), a3=c ("a31","a32","a33"))`
`>list2<-list(b1=c("b11","b12"),b2=c("b21","b22"))` 
`> names(list1)`
[1] "a1" "a2" "a3"
`> names(list2)`
[1] "b1" "b2"
I want each one of the elements of the list to be combined with each one of the elements of the other list

#make any empty list with their combination that later on enters a for loop.
`>my_list_2 <- vector("list", length = length(list1)*length(list2))`

#using their indexes to combine them
`>data_fr <- expand.grid(i = seq_along(list2), j = seq_along(list1))[2:1]`
`>data_fr <- apply(data_fr, 1, paste, collapse = "_")`
`>names(my_list_2) <- data_fr`

What I get is:
`> data_fr`
[1] "1_1" "1_2" "2_1" "2_2" "3_1" "3_2".

What I would like to get is "1_b1", "1_b2", "2_b1", "2_b2", "3_b1", "3_b2".
I would like to keep the name of the second list or both of them. Any good ideas or suggestions?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: First you must tag the language of use in order to get help. I am quite sure this is R, but no one will interact with your question if no language is tagged

Comment: `do.call(paste, c(sep='_',expand.grid(names(list1), names(list2))))`

Comment: Yes, it is R I forgot to mention, thank you, this works!!!